# Which one to use Job Scheduler/Alarm Manager/Fire base Job Dispatcher?

Tags: java, android, service

I was studying following tutorial

[Scheduling Background services](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-scheduling-background-services-a-developers-nightmare-c573807c2705)

After reading entire tutorial, i am still confused, which is the best option for me.

> I need to post android specifications along with lat,long to server
>   via api after every one hour, either my application is in background or killed or phone rebooted.

Which is the best option for me as i want to target API level 15+

- As i see Job Scheduler available in API 21 and above
- GCM Network Manager is deprecated.
- Alarm manager not being used.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Job Scheduler is a good option, as API 21 is kinda the base line for the apps nowdays, Android 4.0 and below are no longer supported.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Try Job manager from Evernote https://github.com/evernote/android-job

Comment: hi Thommy, evernote supports 15 or 18+ devices?